# Non-salience memories?

Tags: memory, theoretical-neuroscience, brain, long-term-memory

It is said that memories that are significant are remembered much more clearly due to salience. Yet, let us imagine a man named Fred. Fred does not have hyperthymesia as he forgets things like everyone else; yet he also has a large amount of non-salient memories. Nitty gritty things like the dialogue someone said in a specific interaction. What is wrong with Fred’s brain? Why does he have so many non-salient memories but not a perfect memory?